# Tomcat: Redirect 403 to 404

Tags: tomcat

I am running Tomcat 8.0.30, and want to redirect all requests that result in a 403 (Forbidden) to 404 (Not Found).  The idea is that if someone uses something like DirBuster, it will look like any files/directories that result in a 403 error are not there.  I have found numerous tutorials online for accomplishing this with Apache HTTP Server, but nothing for Tomcat.  How can I create something like a redirect/rewrite rule to redirect 403 to 404?  Thank you for you insight.

Comment: You may be able to use the answer from this SO article to achieve your desired result: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444359/redirect-403-error-using-htaccess">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444359/redirect-403-error-using-htaccess</a> I believe .htaccess would work the same in Tomcat as in Apache.

Comment: There is no .htaccess in Apache Tomcat